# Download files from a Box location using API

Tags: python, unix, curl, box

How to download files from a Box location programmatically?

I have a shared box location URL(Not the exact path of the box location).

I want to download all the files under the location.

I checked below sdk to connect to box but unable to find methods/library to download files from a shared link.

https://github.com/box/box-python-sdk

```
from boxsdk import Client
from boxsdk import OAuth2

oauth = OAuth2(
    client_id='XXX',
    client_secret='XXX',
    store_tokens='XXX',
)


data = client.make_request(
    'GET',
    '<Shared BOX URL>',
)
```

Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get metadata of shared Box link:

```
shared_folder = client.get_shared_item("https://app.box.com/s/0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef")
```

Loop through each item inside the folder and download each file using [`boxsdk.object.file.File.content`](http://box-python-sdk.readthedocs.io/en/latest/boxsdk.object.html#boxsdk.object.file.File.content) or [`boxsdk.object.file.File.download_to`](http://box-python-sdk.readthedocs.io/en/latest/boxsdk.object.html#boxsdk.object.file.File.download_to):

```
for item in shared_folder.get_items(limit=1000):
    if item.type == 'file':
        # Get file contents into memory
        file_contents = client.file(file_id=item.id).content()
        # Or download to file
        client.file(file_id=item.id).download_to(item.name)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the method that gives you the direct URL:

```
download_url = client.file(file_id='SOME_FILE_ID').get_shared_link_download_url()
```

And then you can use urlib to download it to your local computer:

```
import urllib
urllib.urlretrieve (download_url , your_local_file_name)
```

Could it solve your problem?

Comment: Can you help me understand what should be passed as the file_id. I have the shared box url which has multiple files. I need to download all the files under the shared directory. Can I pass any wildcharacter like '*'

Comment: @Munesh ```items = client.folder(folder_id=FOLDER_ID).get_items(limit=100, offset=0)                                                                                             
FILENAME = "NAME_OF_YOUR_FILE.csv"
FILE_ID = [x.id for x in items if x.name == FILENAME] ``` Of course you need the folder id, which is in the URL when you navigate to the folder.

Answer (score 0):

Pre-requisite:

```
oauth = OAuth2(
    client_id = 'strBoxClientID',
    client_secret = 'strBoxClientSecret', 
    access_token = access_token,
    )
client = Client(oauth)
```

Initial attempt (failed, it produces an empty file):

```
with open(Box_File.name, 'wb') as open_file:
    client.file(Box_File.id).download_to(open_file)
    open_file.close()
```

Final solution:

```
output_file = open('strFilePath' + str(Box_File.name), 'wb')
Box_File.download_to(output_file)
```